# Как добавить числа с++

Tags: c++

Нужно сгенерировать числа, и вывести те, которые больше 0 и меньше 1, с этим проблем нет, но их ещё нужно добавить (т.е допустим вывело 0.5 и 0.9, нужно найти их суму), а это я не понимаю как реализовать, вот сам код (И ещё нужно как-то сделать, чтобы пользователь сам вводил кол-во генерируемых чисел, пока это 50, но я тоже не понимаю как это реализовать)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    srand(time(0));

    const int size = 50;
    double array[size];


    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        array[i] = (rand() % 380 - 190) / 10.0;


    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] >= 0 && array[i] < 1) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Numbers between 0 and 1 --> " << array[i]; 
            cout << endl;
            //cout << "Sum --> " << array[i] + array[i];
            //cout << endl;
        }
    }


    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> И ещё нужно как-то сделать, чтобы пользователь сам вводил кол-во
> генерируемых чисел, пока это 50, но я тоже не понимаю как это
> реализовать

выводите текст через `std::cout <<`

получаете от пользователя ввод через `std::cin >>`

*вам разве этого не давали на занятиях?*

массив в этом случае придётся делать динамическим - выделять под него память

вместо:

```
double array[size];
```

надо будет сделать:

```
double *array = new double[size];
```

> но их ещё нужно добавить (т.е допустим вывело 0.5 и 0.9, нужно найти
> их суму),

если я правильно понял русский, то требуется сделать

```
double sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (array[i] >= 0.5 && array[i] < 0.9) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
}
```

P.S.

почему такие вопросы чаще всего в воскресенье возникают?

Comment: Потому что в понедельник будут проверять домашнее задание?

Answer (score 0):

Массив тут вообще не нужен. А когда пишете код, сначала напишите саму логику, а потом добавьте все выводы, которые захотите (эти сообщения на консоль далеко не самая важная часть кода). Код без сообщений может выглядеть:

```
int size;
double sum = 0, el;
cin >> size;

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    cin >> el;
    if (el > 0 && el < 1)
        sum += el;
}
cout << el;
```